# Sleep system call and its time parameter

Tags: process, c, sleep, thread

Let's say that we are writing a C program that calls the sleep() function. For instance, by calling sleep(7), the calling thread would be put to sleep for 7 seconds.

My question is: Will the thread awake after 7 seconds of our time/clock, or it could take longer, given the fact that each process has its own quantum time on the CPU, because there are many processes running consecutively?

Comment: It will be woken *not earlier than 7 seconds of wall clock* later. That might be in almost exactly 7 seconds, or (if lots of higher priority processes come in between) later, even much later.

Comment: @vonbrand, no that's simply not true. Please read (both) answers for a reason why

Answer (score 5):

The definition of `sleep(3)` allows for the call to return *before*, *at*, or *after* the time specified:

> **DESCRIPTION** `sleep()`  makes  the  calling  thread  sleep  until seconds seconds have elapsed or a signal arrives which is not ignored.

So we have these possible scenarios

1. The call is interrupted with an uncaught signal. `sleep()` returns immediately and before the specified time
2. The call completes satisfactorily, but the system is so busy it can't schedule your task for some time
3. The call complete satisfactorily and is put back on the run queue and executed immediately

Answer (score 2):

POSIX guarantees you that a successful, uninterrupted sleep will sleep at for least as long as you request:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/sleep.html

On Linux, it may take longer due to 1) rounding 2) waiting on the scheduler to put the process/thread on the CPU 3) time spent in a stopped state:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html